# How can I see which jQuery function is bound to the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I found a site, which has some function that I need, in javascript. It's using jQuery, when I click an  tag, some function is executed, so jQuery sets a bind for  tag. But how can I find out which function is bound with it? Firebug didn't show it to me :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wanted to say see the `click` event handler for an element, you'd get the first handler like this:

```
$("#element").data("events").click[0].handler
```

This would give you the function running.  [Here's an example page showing that](http://jsfiddle.net/nyFnt/)

Here's an example:

```
$("a").click(function() {
  alert($("a").data("events").click[0].handler);
});​
```

On click, this would alert: `function() { alert($("a").data("events").click[0].handler); }`

This is just an example using `click`, but whatever you need it for works, `mouseenter`, `focus`, whatever the event may be, including custom events.

As an aside, if you wanted to loop over all event handlers for an element or collection, this would work, just change the selector to what you're after ([here's the same example updated to include this](http://jsfiddle.net/nyFnt/3/)):

```
$.each($("a").data("events"), function(i, e) {
  $.each(e, function(j, h) {
    alert('Event: ' + i + '\nHandler:\n' + h.handler);
  });
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/)? Should be installed in everybody's Firefox/Firebug setup.